# C# TCP Network Stream .Реакция на получаемые данные из уже открытого подключения

Tags: c#, сеть, потоки-данных, tcp

Не понимаю, как мне реагировать на получение данных из потока от подключения(TcpClient.GetStream()). В коде описание работы.

Метод, в котором мы реагируем на появлении новых данных в потоке.

```
public static async Task<MessageContainer> Deserialization(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    // То, что 2733 это не корректно, знаю. Просто приходит пока только одно сообщение одного размера.
    byte[] buff = new byte[2733];
    //tcpClient.Client.Receive(buff);
    BinaryFormatter formater = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream str = tcpClient.GetStream();
    // Я как понимаю в этой строчке.
    await str.ReadAsync(buff, 0, 2733);
    MemoryStream mstr = new MemoryStream(buff);

    // Раньше работало так. При подключении просто была эта строка, которая читала из NetworkStream. Возможно внутри он его закрывает,но
    // под Debug поток открыт еще.
    var answer = (MessageContainer)formater.Deserialize(mstr);

    Console.WriteLine(answer.Data.DataObjects.SingleOrDefault());
    return answer;
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Как реагировать на появлении новых данных в потоке?

Мне этот метод зациклить нужно?

Comment: То, что работающие методы по сути не делают то, что надо(всмысле почему Deserialization реагирует на получение данных, а не соотв метод) я знаю. Интересует как реагировать вообще.

Comment: Обрежьте все лишнее и сделайте минимально воспроизводимый код. Я подозреваю у вас ошибка с применением `async/await` но я не могу быть уверен, так как не понятно даже, кто и когда вызывает `HandlePhysicalPortConnectChangeEvent`.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что вы не проверяете возвращаемое значение метода `ReadAsync`.

Comment: @Zergatul OnPhysicalPortConnectChangeEvent// в классе PhysicalPort вызывает HandlePhysicalPortConnectChangeEvent

Comment: @Zergatul насколько я понял, мне значение из ReadAsync вообще не нужно. Убрал его.

Comment: @Zergatul походу нашел вопрос конкретнее. Поменял тело вопроса и сам вопрос.

Comment: Не убирайте результат `ReadAsync`. Выведите его на консоль, и проверьте, действительно ли читается 2733 байт.

Comment: @Zergatul заработало и да, читалось именно оно. Но я не очень понимаю, как мне отсылать сообщения, когда заранее я не знаю его длинну в байтах. Перед этим отправлять int длинной сообщения в байтах? Равзе TCP сам это не делает? Тобишь сколько int в байтах я знаю...Есть другие способы?

Comment: TCP отсылает длину пакетов, но не длину сообщений, которые вы посылаете в `C# `коде. Вам придется самим посылать длину, так как TCP может фрагментировать ваше сообщение на свое усмотрение. В любом случае классы `C#` не предоставляют такого низкоуровневого контроля над TCP.

Comment: @Zergatul да, уже догадался. Пакет у меня в памяти ассоциировался с моим сообщением.

Comment: @Arantler: TCP — потоковый протокол, низкоуровневый. В него можно лишь записывать и читать из него поток байт. Структуру поверх этого организовывать нужно вам самостоятельно. Ну или используйте WCF, там это всё уже сделано.

Comment: @VladD меня смущает, что сообщения в виде XML структур происходит. Я хочу передавать объекты через BinaruFormatter, а насколько я знаю, WCF на автомате общение через XML делает(парсить все это дело стоит больше, чем десериализовать объекты. Да и удобнее(все ссылки на другие объекты сохраняются и передается, считай, состояние).

Comment: @Arantler: Не совсем так. WCF можно настроить в зависимости от того, что вам нужно: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/specifying-data-transfer-in-service-contracts. Ну и не забывайте, что скорость распаковки XML намного больше, чем скорость передачи по сети. Так что может быть вы ищете ложную экономию.